# Migrate Email templates from Personal email templates folder

Tags: email-template

What is the best way to move email templates from Personal Email Template folders of all users from one production org to another? ANT will only extract personal email templates of the running user. Will dataloader export give me a list of all public and personal email templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used Data loader to extract all the email templates and replaced the BrandTemplateId with letterhead Id of target org and folder ids by the user id under whom you want the  Personal Email template to show up. Did an import in the target org and the templates got created correctly.